# $(JML)$ and $(JNL)$ respectively cuts $CK$ and $BK$ at $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $\overline{J, N, P}$ and $\overline{J, M, Q}$.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

> $E$ and $F$ are points respectively lying on $AB$ and $CA$ such that $B, C, E, F$ are concyclic. $BF \cap CE = K$. $KM \perp CA$ and $KN \perp AB$ $(M \in CA$ and $N \in AB)$ and $L$ is the midpoint of $AK$. $I$ and $J$ are points lying respectively on $EF$ and $BC$ such that $\angle AKI = \angle KJI$. $(JML)$ and $(JNL)$ respectively cuts $CK$ and $BK$ at $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $\overline{J, N, P}$ and $\overline{J, M, Q}$. Note that $I$ is the midpoint of $EF$.

[image]

It can be seen, but not proven, that $J$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

We might be able to establish that $MNPQ$ is a parallelogram, perhaps even an isosceles parallelogram. But I am one of "us".

Comment: Are you assuming that $I$ is the midpoint of $EF$?

Comment: Yup. I forgot to write that.

Comment: Where do you keep finding these elaborate questions?

Comment: Studying advanced stuff for a year and ignore all the basics. That's how our class are determined to enter competitions.

Comment: The quadrilateral $MNPQ$ does not look as a parallelogram.

Comment: I think that such point $J$ is not unique (circumcircle of $(IKJ)$ intersects $BC$ at two points including $J$).